# How to fix Visual Tracker Benchmark error

Tags: python, matlab

I will be glad for any help to fix this

I have found a Benchmark [dataset](http://cvlab.hanyang.ac.kr/tracker_benchmark/datasets.html) with ground truth data, in order to test Tracker algorithms, I had downloaded their [source code](https://github.com/jwlim/tracker_benchmark), I followed the instructions in readme file :

1. I setup MATLAB engine for Python code
2. I had installed matplotlib `python -m pip install matplotlib`
3. I had installed numpy python -m pip install numpy `python -m pip install numpy`
4. I had installed [Python Imaging Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0) (PIL)

in the readme file they said

> - command : python run_trackers.py -t "tracker" -s "sequence" -e "evaltype"

so I choosed [Fish dataset](http://cvlab.hanyang.ac.kr/tracker_benchmark/seq/Fish.zip), then when I run `python run_trackers.py -t IVT -s Fish -e OPE,SRE,TRE`, an erro messege shows up for missing `.mat` files for the tracker alogithms `tracker_benchmark-master\trackers\IVT`, I got them [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~dross/ivt/)

at this point, I did everything no missing file, Matlab, PIL libs and python have the same version 64bit.

> I only have to execute the command

```
python run_trackers.py -t IVT -s Fish -e OPE
```

but unfortunately I got this errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, even I have installed python 64 bits the numpy package was incompatible, so I look for numpy 64 bits libs in this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), but you have to check your python version which architecture (32 bit or 64 bit) your python is? (you can do it so by opening python idle and typing)

```
import platform  
platform.architecture()
```

1. I downloaded the proper version like cp27 (means for python 2.7) and cp36(means for python 3.6) and so on.  in my case I have python 2.7 64 bits so i get `numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`
2. open cmd Prompt get where you have downloaded the `.whl` file, then run

   `python -m pip install "numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl"`

[image]

1. then I run Visual Tracker Benchmark code successfully yopy ^-^

   `python run_trackers.py -t IVT -s Fish -e OPE`

[image]

Comment: running `python draw_graph.py` if it gives you an error it means import matplotlib incompatible just uninstall it `python -m pip uninstall matplotlib`, then get the `.whl` file and install it again `python -m pip install matplotlib-2.1.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`